# particle motion in 1D anharmonic well

Tags: plotting, graphics, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, physics

I have set of data points but I want to draw the trajectory of particle moving inside this well either in phase space. How can I do this? I tried with `VectorPlot` but not come out with good and set of data point are as follows: mass of particle is 10^-24 kg and here in this data first column is position & second potential. I am very thankful to you if you can help me to do this. Thank you.

```
x={2.*10^-6, 1.9*10^-6, 1.8*10^-6, 1.7*10^-6, 1.6*10^-6, 1.5*10^-6, 
     1.4*10^-6, 1.3*10^-6, 1.2*10^-6, 1.1*10^-6, 1.*10^-6, 9.*10^-7, 
     8.*10^-7, 7.*10^-7, 6.*10^-7, 5.*10^-7, 4.*10^-7, 3.*10^-7, 2.*10^-7,
      1.*10^-7, 0, -1.*10^-7, -2.*10^-7, -3.*10^-7, -4.*10^-7, -5.*10^-7, \
    -6.*10^-7, -7.*10^-7, -8.*10^-7, -9.*10^-7, -1.*10^-6, -1.1*10^-6, \
    -1.2*10^-6, -1.3*10^-6, -1.4*10^-6, -1.5*10^-6, -1.6*10^-6, \
    -1.7*10^-6, -1.8*10^-6, -1.9*10^-6, -2.*10^-6}  

 Vx = {-2.39203*10^-19, -2.38026*10^-19, -2.37166*10^-19, -2.36809*10^-19, \
-2.37117*10^-19, -2.38208*10^-19, -2.40143*10^-19, -2.42925*10^-19, \
-2.46503*10^-19, -2.50782*10^-19, -2.55644*10^-19, -2.60954*10^-19, \
-2.6657*10^-19, -2.72342*10^-19, -2.78094*10^-19, -2.83618*10^-19, \
-2.88644*10^-19, -2.92835*10^-19, -2.95779*10^-19, -2.97001*10^-19, \
-2.96*10^-19, -2.92287*10^-19, -2.8545*10^-19, -2.75213*10^-19, \
-2.61492*10^-19, -2.44433*10^-19, -2.24423*10^-19, -2.0208*10^-19, \
-1.782*10^-19, -1.53693*10^-19, -1.29492*10^-19, -1.06466*10^-19, \
-8.5334*10^-20, -6.6606*10^-20, -5.0546*10^-20, -3.7171*10^-20, \
-2.6278*10^-20, -1.75*10^-20, -1.0373*10^-20, -4.409*10^-21, 
 1.*10^-21}
```

Comment: what are your initial conditions?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a general answer. I am rescaling your values for convenience.

```
x = x 10^6;
Vx = Vx 10^19;

pot[y_] = Interpolation[Transpose[{x , Vx }]][y]; (*potential function*)
f[y_] = -D[pot[y], y]; (*function for force*)

y0 = 0.2; (*initial position*)
v0 = 0.5; (*initial velocity*)
tmax = 10;(*time range*) 
m=1;
(*now solve m y''[t]==f[y] within 0<t<tmax*)
sol[t] = y[t] /. NDSolve[{m y''[t] == f[y[t]], y[0]==y0, y'[0]==v0}, y[t], {t, 0, tmax}];

z[t_] = sol[t][[1]];  (*in case of multiple solutions, take the first one*)
v[t_] = D[z[t], t];
```

**Animated Oscillation**

```
Animate[Plot[pot[y], {y, x[[1]], x[[-1]]}, 
        Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{z[t], pot[z[t]]}],
                   Arrow[{{z[t], pot[z[t]]}, {z[t] + m v[t], pot[z[t]]}}]}, 
       FrameLabel -> {"x", "V(x)"}, Frame -> True], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]

**Compare the phase space trajectory and real motion**

```
Animate[Grid[
{{Plot[z[t1], {t1, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x"},
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{t, z[t]}]}],
  Plot[v[t1], {t1, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "v"}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{t, v[t]}]}]},
 {ParametricPlot[{z[t1], v[t1]}, {t1, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "v"}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{z[t], v[t]}]}],
  Plot[pot[y], {y, x[[1]], x[[-1]]}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{z[t], pot[z[t]]}], Arrow[{{z[t], pot[z[t]]}, {z[t] + m v[t], pot[z[t]]}}]}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "V(x)"}, Frame -> True]}}], {t, 0, tmax}]]
```

[image]

**Phase space diagram**

Here I choose a large set of initial condition to span the phase space and choose a small time to see the instantaneous motion.

```
yv0 = Flatten[Table[{y, v}, {y, -0.401, 0.6, 0.05}, {v, -0.601, 0.65, 0.05}], 1];
(*initila y0,v0*)
nn = Length[yv0];(*number of inital data*)

tmax = 0.2;
m = 1;

data = Table[ sol[t] = 
y[t] /. NDSolve[{m y''[t] == f[y[t]], y[0] == yv0[[n, 1]], 
   y'[0] == yv0[[n, 2]]}, y[t], {t, 0, tmax}];
z[t_] = sol[t][[1]];
v[t_] = D[z[t], t];
 {{z[0], v[0]}, {z[tmax], v[tmax]} - {z[0], v[0]}},
{n, nn}];

ListVectorPlot[data, VectorStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 0.6}, {-0.6, 0.6}},
FrameLabel -> {"x", "Vx"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can't we plot vector plot for this????

Comment: To do that you need a list of initial conditions each of which will give a trajectory. Then you can make a `ListVectorPlot`.

Comment: Thanku so much for your efforts. Actually my main target is to see motion of particle when my one axis follow this potential and other axis has harmonic 1/2kq^2. Can you please help me in that?? I will be highly Thank full to you.

Comment: @user51734, check my modification. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much for such a good visualization. Since we know motion is always three dimensional so here the data I provided is only 1D but lets assume I have V(x)=given data +1/2y^2. Then I want to see How particle will move in 3D.

Comment: m = 0.5*10^-24;
vdat = Table[{q[[j]], v[[j]]}, {j, 1, 40}];
vf = Interpolation[vdat];
Plot[vf[x], {x, q[[1]], q[[40]]}]
force[x_] = -D[vf[x], {x, 1}];
Plot[force[x], {x, q[[1]], q[[40]]}]
VectorPlot[{y/(m), force[x]}, {x, q[[1]], q[[40]]}, {y, -4*10^(-22), 
  4*10^(-22)}, PlotRange -> All, VectorStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1,
  FrameLabel -> {Style["q (\[Mu]m)", 16], Style["p (Ns)", 16]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 7], FrameStyle -> Directive[Thin, 14]]

Comment: I wrote this code for phase space here don't need to give initial condition if you can make path very clear for this that could also be helpful thanku.

Comment: here q is position and v is potential.

Comment: use `vf[x_] = Interpolation[vdat][x];`. To make your plot better you can use [`VectorPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPoints.html) and [`StreamPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPoints.html).

Comment: I tried to plot vector point and streampoints but due to very small range I am looking it didn't work?? But actually what I want is the animated one you plot in that over time it is oscillating the particle but after some time it may go out from the potential.

Comment: Now your questions are going more mathematics than mathematica. If you give a high initial velocity you will make a rocket out of your pendulum and run away from any potential. Initial condition and data range are always tricky ;)

Comment: I think you got my question wrongly my in short meaning is can we plot momentum to be gradually increasing over time as simple as is that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: Try `Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{z[t], pot[z[t]]}], 
  Arrow[{{z[t], pot[z[t]]}, {z[t] + m v[t], pot[z[t]]}}]}` . It will show the momentum as an arrow. I will update my answer later.

Comment: My meaning of the statement is let us suppose particle is moving with particular momentum but that momentum will increase over time if momentum will increase then particle will also change there path and over time if momentum is so much high then particle will go out how that could be incorporate in animation I tried it by changing z[t] but it shows some wrong results that what i mean is.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning anything to `V(x)` is not proper syntax. But this works:

```
x = {2.*10^-6, 1.9*10^-6, 1.8*10^-6, 1.7*10^-6, 1.6*10^-6, 1.5*10^-6, 
   1.4*10^-6, 1.3*10^-6, 1.2*10^-6, 1.1*10^-6, 1.*10^-6, 9.*10^-7, 
   8.*10^-7, 7.*10^-7, 6.*10^-7, 5.*10^-7, 4.*10^-7, 3.*10^-7, 
   2.*10^-7, 1.*10^-7, 
   0, -1.*10^-7, -2.*10^-7, -3.*10^-7, -4.*10^-7, -5.*10^-7, \
-6.*10^-7, -7.*10^-7, -8.*10^-7, -9.*10^-7, -1.*10^-6, -1.1*10^-6, \
-1.2*10^-6, -1.3*10^-6, -1.4*10^-6, -1.5*10^-6, -1.6*10^-6, \
-1.7*10^-6, -1.8*10^-6, -1.9*10^-6, -2.*10^-6};

V = {-2.39203*10^-19, -2.38026*10^-19, -2.37166*10^-19, \
-2.36809*10^-19, -2.37117*10^-19, -2.38208*10^-19, -2.40143*10^-19, \
-2.42925*10^-19, -2.46503*10^-19, -2.50782*10^-19, -2.55644*10^-19, \
-2.60954*10^-19, -2.6657*10^-19, -2.72342*10^-19, -2.78094*10^-19, \
-2.83618*10^-19, -2.88644*10^-19, -2.92835*10^-19, -2.95779*10^-19, \
-2.97001*10^-19, -2.96*10^-19, -2.92287*10^-19, -2.8545*10^-19, \
-2.75213*10^-19, -2.61492*10^-19, -2.44433*10^-19, -2.24423*10^-19, \
-2.0208*10^-19, -1.782*10^-19, -1.53693*10^-19, -1.29492*10^-19, \
-1.06466*10^-19, -8.5334*10^-20, -6.6606*10^-20, -5.0546*10^-20, \
-3.7171*10^-20, -2.6278*10^-20, -1.75*10^-20, -1.0373*10^-20, \
-4.409*10^-21, 1.*10^-21};

ListPlot[Transpose[{x, V}]]
```

[image]

Comment: My question is not about plotting its about motion. And V(x) is just data point.