# Numerically Solving non-linear pendulum differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

[image]I would like to numerically solve the following equation.

```
y''[x] == -(g/l) Sin[x]
```

I have tried the following code.

```
NDSolve[y''[x] == -(g/l) Sin[x], u, {x, 0, 2pi}]
```

I'm not sure what the u is supposed to mean. I also get an error for the `2pi`.

Comment: `2pi` is nothing in Mathematica. You want `2Pi`. Capitalization matters.

Comment: [particle motion in 1D anharmonic well](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161690/particle-motion-in-1d-anharmonic-well/161701#161701) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Numerical solution:**

For a numerical solution you need to specify all the parameters, i.e., `g`, `l`. In *Mathematica* the correct syntax for pi is `Pi`. `u` should be replaced by the dependent variable `y`. Moreover, you also need to include initial/boundary conditions.

```
g = 1; l = 1;

sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] == -(g/l) Sin[x], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]

Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

**Analytical solution:**

```
sol = First@DSolve[{y''[x] == -(g/l) Sin[x], y[0] == a, y'[0] == b}, y[x], x]

Plot[y[x] /. sol /. {g -> 1, l -> 1, a -> 1, b -> 1}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Note, once again I have chosen randoms values for parameters and initial conditions.

**Edit:**

The OP has modified his original equation,

```
g = 9.8; l = 0.22;

sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] == -(g/l) Sin[y[x]], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]

Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now would it be possible to come up with an equation that would approximate that differential equation with a function?

Comment: I also expected the plot to oscillate, like a pendulum would

Comment: Thanks again. However, I still get a graph that doesn't oscillate. Here's how someone did it in maple (see edited question). The non-linear pendulum should oscillate.

Comment: Sorry, the equation is actually supposed to be x''=(g/l)sinx. Now I understand why it doesn't oscillate. I tried the following: sol = First@DSolve[{y''[x] == -(g/l) Sin[y], y[0] == a, y'[0] == b}, y[x], x]

Plot[y[x] /. sol /. {g -> 1, l -> 1, a -> 1, b -> 1}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}]    I still get an error.

Comment: Try `sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] == -(g/l) Sin[y[x]], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
  y, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]`

Comment: I got an error when I tried the code. Did u get an oscillating graph?

Comment: @OmkarVaidya have you included the values for g and l?

Comment: @zhk The value for g is supposed to be 9.8 and l is supposed to be 0.22m.

Comment: @zhk I tried this:sol = First@
  DSolve[{y''[x] == -(g/l) Sin[y[x]], y[0] == a, y'[0] == b}, y[x], x]

Plot[y[x] /. sol /. {g -> 9.8, l -> .22, a -> 1, b -> 1}, {x, 0, 
  2*Pi}]

Comment: @zhk Thanks! Last thing: I tried getting an an analytical solution by using your code, but changed it a bit, and I get an error. sol = First@
  DSolve[{y''[x] == -(g/l) Sin[y[x]], y[0] == a, y'[0] == b}, y[x]]

Plot[y[x] /. sol /. {g -> 9.8, l -> .22, a -> 1, b -> 1}, {x, 0, 
  2*Pi}]

Comment: @OmkarVaidya General analytical solution is possible but not a particular one for the initial conditions we are using.

Comment: @zhk I'm just looking for an approximation for the differential equation. Are you sure mathematica can't do it? Just look up non-linear pendulum differential equation. I found this site that said it would be possible. http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/Pendulum/Pendula.html

Comment: @OmkarVaidya If you read the material carefully in the link, you will find that it says that no closed form solution is possible? Even it says that numerical solution can be found using `NDSolve`.

Comment: yes, I understood that part. I am looking for an approximation for it though. Like the graph it just drew, would it be possible to have a function that would closely follow the graph? Else, it would be fine if I were able to locate certain points in the graph

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72162/discussion-between-omkar-vaidya-and-zhk).